# C# DateTime parses two date strings milliseconds apart incorrectly and gives negative unix time

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I'm trying to convert date strings to Unix time using dotnet 6 and during my testing, I found a strange result between two timestamps that are milliseconds apart. My conversion code is (commented out bits are the variations I've tried and the results are the same):

```cs
static long convert_to_unix_time(DateTime date){ 
    return new DateTimeOffset(date, TimeSpan.Zero).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
}
    
static DateTime convert_to_timestamp(string date, string format) {
    string[] param = new string[1];
    param[0] = format;
        
    var final = new DateTime();
    var parsed_time = DateTime.TryParseExact(
        date,
        param,
        CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-ZA"), //CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, //CultureInfo.Invariant, 
        DateTimeStyles.None,
        out final);
        return final;
    }
```

Running this:

```cs
var date1 = "20201214 13:00:04.156";
var date2 = "20201214 12:59:59.999";
string format = "yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss.fff";
        
var final1 = convert_to_timestamp(date1, format);
var unix_time1 = convert_to_unix_time(final1);
        
Console.WriteLine("final1 is: {0}", final1.ToString(format));
Console.WriteLine("unix time1 is: {0}", unix_time1);
        
var final2 = convert_to_timestamp(date2, format);
var unix_time2 = convert_to_unix_time(final2);
        
Console.WriteLine("final2 is: {0}", final2.ToString(format));
Console.WriteLine("unix time2 is: {0}", unix_time2);
```

The output I get is:

```
final1 is: 00010101 12:00:00.000
unix time1 is: -62135596800000
final2 is: 20201214 12:59:59.999
unix time2 is: 1607907599999
```

I can't for the life of me figure out what's causing this error, or even what to call it or search for.

Is there a way to get the correct result?

[dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mas4lW)

Comment: 24h hour format is HH, not hh

Comment: I'd strongly suggest that if you're going to use a `TryParseXxx` method (on any type) and *ignore the return value*, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Both those functions, as I've written them, are unit tested, that's how I discovered the error. Unless I'm missing what you're saying. @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: `parsed_time` in `convert_to_timestamp` tells you whether or not `TryParseExact` succeeded in it's task. However, you completely ignore that and *assume* that it did succeed. Any time it fails you just get back the default value of `DateTime` and return that.

Comment: For this particular problem, it would have still returned true, which wouldn't have helped. However, I didn't think of that! Still makes sense to check. Thanks for the tip, much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uppercase "H" indicates a 24-hour time and lowercase "h" indicates 12-hour time. [More information on string formats here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

You are sending a 24h string to a 12h format.

Updated code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/wkYoQY

```
string format = "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.fff";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use  "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.fff" instead of  "yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss.fff"